# Do you capitalize the names of governments in a story?

Tags: dialogue, description, punctuation, grammar

I know that names of countries, states, cities, and counties are always capitalized, but what about governments and organizations? In my novella there are basically 2 sections of space, and each have their own names. So in dialogue and in description do the names of factions, governments, and organizations need to be capitalized, or do I leave it uncapitalized?

Comment: Hi Abram. This question is probably suited better for English Language SE. It's borderline, so others might correct me here, but I believe it is more  a general grammar question than a question about how to write with grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Proper names get capitalized. Generic names don't.

- Federal Bureau of Sparkly Vampires
- Department of Redundancy Department
- Imperial Dogwalkers Consortium
- The Sacred Order of Turnip Twaddlers
- The Church of Saint Spock the Pointy-Eared
- The United Provinces of Cumberbatch
- the Hiddlestoners Rebellion
- Judean People's Front (not to be confused with the People's Front of Judea)

but

- the Cumberbatchian government
- the rebels
- cat lovers of the Empire
- tautologists
- those who twaddle turnips
- hobbyist turnip-twaddlers

Comment: Is it considered a proper name if one of factions is referred to as The Syndicate? Also, what about the areas of space these two factions control? Would they be capitalized as well?

Comment: Yes. 'The Syndicate' in this context is referring to a specific organization, and as such is a proper noun. '*A* syndicate,' referring to perhaps a type of organization, would not be capitalized. As for the space, as long as you are referring to a specific name of an area, it is proper and capitalized. Simply saying 'their territory' or something similar is not proper, and is not capitalized. Similarly, 'the Syndicate's lands' is not capitalized, but the specific name of those lands is: 'Gahooza, province of the Syndicate.'

Comment: Stylistically, if you haven't done so, I would give proper names to your space regions: the *Neutral Zone*, *Orion's Nebula*, the *Delta Quadrant*, rather than *demilitarized zone*, *giant nebula* and the like

Comment: I've thought about that, just not sure how I want to go about it until I do a little more world building. Like there's the area of space beyond those borders that they would refer to as Cvil Order, or Syndicate space, and then there are regions within those borders.